# AWS Identity Token Vending Machine - Android Code Error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, tvm

I am using;

- Eclipse Juno
- ADT-22.3.0
- aws-android-sdk-1.7.0

For using AWS Token Vending machine code I used sample code for android from below link;
http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367

As per instructions I added following libs to project classpath;

- aws-android-sdk-1.7.0-debug.jar
- aws-android-sdk-1.7.0.jar

and when I run in emulator and device; I receive following error at runtime (no error at compile time)

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils
    at com.amazonaws.tvmclient.Utilities.getTimestamp(Utilities.java:28)
    at com.amazonaws.tvmclient.LoginRequest.buildRequestUrl(LoginRequest.java:50)
....
```

However, in code when I checked - the class is imported and there are no compile time errors

```
import com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils;
```

and here how it is used in code (Utilities class sample code);

```
new DateUtils().formatIso8601Date( new Date() );
```

would appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update the Eclipse project settings to ensure all classes are exported for Dexing.  Please take a look at the instructions at the following blog post and see if this solves your issue:

[Running AWS SDK for Android samples in Eclipse with ADT v22](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20QCGGQZLH23U/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont add both

1. aws-android-sdk-1.7.0-debug.jar
2. aws-android-sdk-1.7.0.jar

into your classpath. During run time, it creates conflict regarding class files because both the jars have class files with common name.

Either use aws-android-sdk-1.7.0-debug.jar  which creates the largest APK, but allows for full stack traces during development. or

Add aws-android-sdk-VERSION.jar  which creates a smaller APK and a simple bundle when releasing your application.